# Ошибка при перегрузке оператора "+"

Tags: c++

oop.h

```
#pragma once
class Money
{
private:
    unsigned long long rubles;
    unsigned char penny;
public:
    Money operator+(Money &v1);
};
```

oop.cpp

```
Money Money::operator+(Money &v1)
{
    return Money(this->rubles+v1.rubles);
}
```

Ошибка под "this": Не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "unsigned long long" в "Money".

Comment: Вам же компилятор открытым тестом сказал, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно написать конструктор, который будет принимать `unsigned long long`.

Суда по вашему классу, это должно быть что-то вроде

```
Money(unsigned long long rubles, unsigned char penny = 0)
:rubles(rubles),penny(penny){}
```

Только вот почему вы при суммировании суммируете только рубли? А копейки?

Comment: А как суммировать их одновременно?

Comment: [А как суммировать их одновременно?] Может быть переводить все суммы в копейки и суммировать? И вообще работать в копейках, а рубли только при печати отделять от копеек.